# Как вернуть предварительный просмотр окон на панели задач?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Раньше у меня на панели задач несколько окон отображались, как на рисунке 1. После непонятных мне изменений они стали отображаться как на рисунке 2. Что исправить, чтобы несколько окон отображались, как на рисунке 1?

**Рисунок 1:** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Рисунок 2:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]